# How to make the registration correctly?

Tags: c++, static-members

I have a factory class to register a type

```
class Factory
{
public:
    template<class T>
    static void regist()
    {
        mMap[T::type()] = [](){return new T();};
    }

    static Base* create(string type)
    {
       ... // use map to find the function to create a new object
    }

private:
    static map<string, function<Base* ()>> mMap;
};

map<string, function<Base* ()>> Factory::mMap;
```

and a concrete class T of Base

```
class A : public Base
{
public:
    static string type() { return "A"; }
    static bool sRegist;
    A() {}

};

bool A::sRegist = []() -> bool {
    Factory::regist<A>();
    return true;
}();
```

However, the code crashes when run. I think it is due to the indefinite initialization order of the static memebers. How to make it works? Thanks.

Comment: `bool A::sRegist = Factory::regist<A>();` should work? (Sorry, didn't get initially what the code was doing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place `mMap` inside static function, like this:

```
class Factory
{
public:
  template<class T>
  static void regist()
  {
    getMap()[T::type()] = [](){return new T();};
  }

  // ...

private:
  static map<string, function<Base* ()>>& getMap() {
    static map<string, function<Base* ()>> mMap;
    return mMap;
  }
};
```

In this case the `mMap` will be initialized as soon as function gets invoked.

Comment: Very smart. My first comment is from your very early answer.